# Sails.js Upload File With Semantic-UI Progress Bar Not Working

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, sails.js, semantic-ui

I'm building a module for uploading files using the Sails.js framework.

Now I want to use progress bar from Semantic-UI, but the code I've tried below only works after the upload process has finished.

How can I make the progress bar show the actual progress of the upload?

```
<form action="/fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ui form" method="post">

    <div class="field">
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="ui blue submit button" />
    </div>

</form>

<div class="ui indicating progress" data-percent="0" id="uploadProgress">
    <div class="bar" style="transition-duration: 300ms; width: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="label"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#uploadProgress').progress('increment');
</script>
```